# multiple kinect

Tags: ros, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to display pointclouds from two kinects! Actually I've instantied two openni_node (one for each kinect), remapping the topic from "camera" to, respectively, "kinect1" and "kinect2". Then I've created two other nodes that subscribe /kinect/rgb/points and, rototranslate one of the two flows.

But, when I try to visualize the output, the result is a very low frame rate video with a substantial delay!!

What can i do??

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10041/multiple-kinect/) by [fberga](https://answers.ros.org/users/585/fberga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-05-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look here [first topic](http://answers.ros.org/question/973/connecting-two-kinects-with-openni_camera-will) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/923/is-it-possible-to-use-more-than-one-kinect-with)

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1